# Crystal reports not appearing in my Add references?

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have installed the crystal reports runtime (CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_9.msi)

when I go to visual studio 2008, and click on add refernces, in the .NET tab, I can't find any Crystal reports components??  Does anyone know how to get them to appear?  I assumed by installing the run time that would have installed the assemblies as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to browse to the location that you installed the binaries and select it manually. I am not sure that assemblies are always added to the list that appears in 'Add References'. Once you have added it once, it should then appear in the Recent list.

Comment: I thought that.. but there are a whole heap of assemblies in the installed location, but nothing resembling the common crystal ones like CrystalDecisions.Web ... they are a heap of them like commonobjmodel_res_en.dll

Answer (score 0):

Download and execute the [CRforVS_13_0_9.exe](http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_13_0_9.exe) package. Sometimes the msi files don't work as expected. The Crystal Report Community Network mentions in [this article](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824) that "MSI files by definition are for runtime distribution only".